# How to left join or inner join a table itself

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, self-join

I have this data in a table, for instance,

```
id      name        parent      parent_id
1       add         self        100
2       manage      null        100
3       add         10          200
4       manage      null        200
5       add         20          300
6       manage      null        300
```

How can I `left join` or `inner join` this table itself so I get this result below?

```
id      name        parent
2       manage      self
4       manage      10
6       manage      20
```

As you can I that I just want to query the row with the keyword of 'manage' but I want the column `parent`'s data in **add**'s row as the as in **manage**'s row in the result.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

the simplified version of my actual table - `system`,

```
system_id   parent_id   type    function_name       name        main_parent         make_accessible     sort
31          30          left    main                Main        NULL                0                   1
32          31          left    page_main_add       Add         self                0                   1
33          31          left    page_main_manage    Manage      NULL                0                   2
```

my actual query and it is quite messy already...

```
SELECT 
    a.system_id,
    a.main_parent,
    b.name, 
    b.make_accessible, 
    b.sort

FROM system AS a

INNER JOIN -- self --
(
    SELECT system_id, name, make_accessible, sort
    FROM system AS s2

    LEFT JOIN -- search --
    (
    SELECT system_id AS parent_id
    FROM system AS s1
    WHERE s1.function_name = 'page'
    ) AS s1

    ON s1.parent_id = s2.parent_id

    WHERE s2.parent_id = s1.parent_id
    AND s2.system_id != s1.parent_id
    ORDER BY s2.sort ASC
) b
ON b.system_id = a.parent_id


WHERE a.function_name LIKE '%manage%'
ORDER BY b.sort ASC
```

result I get currently,

```
system_id   main_parent     name    make_accessible sort
33          NULL            Main    0                1
```

but I am after this,

```
system_id   main_parent     name    make_accessible sort
33          self            Main    0                1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to reference the table twice:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name
from TableA t1 
  inner join TableA t2
    on t1.parent_id = t2.Id
```

Replace inner with left join if you want to see roots in the list.

**UPDATE:**

I misread your question. It seems to me that you always have two rows, manage one and add one. To get to "Add" from manage:

```
select system.*, (select parent 
                    from system s2 
                   where s2.parent_id = system.parent_id 
                     and s2.name = 'add') 
                 AS parent
from system
where name = 'manage'
```

Or, you might split the table into two derived tables and join them by parent_id:

```
select *
  from system
  inner join
  (
     select * from system where name = 'add'
  ) s2
    on system.parent_id = s2.parent_id
  where system.name = 'manage'
```

This will allow you to use all the columns from s2.

Comment: thanks for the edit and the answer. tested it and got it right. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: Joining by parent_id, try:

```
select m.id, m.name, a.parent
from myTable m
join myTable a on m.parent_id = a.parent_id and a.name = 'add'
where m.name = 'manage'
```

Change the inner join to a left join if there may not be a corresponding **add** row.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on the ID values always being off by one. That seems like a pretty dangerous assumption to me, but perhaps the particular system allows it.

Comment: @MJB: I have updated it to join **add** rows to **manage** rows on parent_id, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your data does not abide to a child-parent hierarchical structure. For example, your column `parent` holds the value `10`, which is not the value of any `id`, so a child-parent association is not possible.

In other words, there's nothing that relates the record `2,manage,null` to the record `1,add,self`, or the record `4,manage,null` to `3,add,10`, as you intend to do in your query.

To represent hierarchical data, you usually need a table that has a foreign key referencing it's own primary key. So your column `parent` must reference the column `id`, then you can express a child-parent relationship between `manage` and `add`. Currently, that's not possible.

Comment: sorry, maybe I should have provided more details and the actual table I am working on. please have a look on my edit above. thanks.